# IIS WCF net.tcp binding error

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-binding, invalidoperationexception, net.tcp

I know there are many questions about this, I'we tried them all and it didn't work...
I'm using IIS8 on WS8, added net.tcp to protocols list and binding to 808 and I still get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

I'm trying to open service in browser using:     `http://192.168.1.101:64410/eve/relay/ClientRelayService.svc`

I'm runing 2 test services (one is basichttp and other should be tcp) on a site with port 64410. Other service is working as should.

Here's mine server side config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <trust level="Full" />
        <httpRuntime/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="tcpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <reliableSession enabled="true" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <services>

            <service name="Eve.API.Services.Relay.RemoteRelayService">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:64410/eve/relay/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Eve.API.Services.Contracts.Services.Interfaces.IEveAPIService"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>

            <service name="Eve.API.Services.Relay.RelayService">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/eve/relay/ClientRelayService.svc"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding" contract="Eve.API.Services.Contracts.Services.Interfaces.IRelayService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="tcpmex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
            </service>

        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- TODO Set to false on deploy -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!-- TODO Set to false on deploy -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the port for the NetTCP binding? I'm not 100% sure http and net.tcp can share the same port via IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove base address from service with net.tcp binding, and define address **explicitly** on it's endpoint, like

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:808/eve/relay/ClientRelayService.svc" 
  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding" 
  contract="Eve.API.Services.Contracts.Services.Interfaces.IRelayService">
```